# Video tag not rendering before playing

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I'm using video tag to display a video in my website. Everything works fine in desktop browser but in chrome mobile browser (android at least) video is not displayed inside the "video container" if I don't push play button. There is a transparent "window" with the play button over it and with the controls below.

I have seen something similar over the internet but there was a light gray background where should be the video before playing it.

I set preload="auto" but it did not work.

```
<video class="img-responsive video" preload="auto" controls>
   <source src="./videos/apresentação.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="./videos/apresentação.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I used `poster` attribute to apply an image inside video tag:

```
<video class="img-responsive video" poster="./videos/poster.jpg" preload="auto" controls>
    <source src="./videos/apresentação.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="./videos/apresentação.webm" type="video/webm">
    <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
</video>
```